# JPA enum query ERROR on playframework

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I am working on project using java playframework 1.2.4 and I have a @Entity class. It is look like

```
@Entity
public class EmployeeType extends Model {
    public static enum TYPE { HOURLY, DAILY, MONTHLY };
    public static enum NATIONALITY { LOCAL, FOREIGN };
    @Required
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public TYPE type;
    @Required
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public NATIONALITY nationality;
}
```

And in my controller class I want to get list of EmployeeTypes using my 2 enum attributes.
Query looks like

```
Query query = JPA.em().createQuery("SELECT e FROM EmployeeType e where " +
            "e.nationality = :nationality " +
            "and e.type = :type");
query.setParameter("nationality", NATIONALITY.LOCAL);
query.setParameter("type", TYPE.HOURLY);

List<models.EmployeeType> employeeType = query.getResultList()
```

Gives this error: IllegalArgumentException occured : Parameter value [LOCAL] was not matching type [models.EmployeeType$NATIONALITY]

What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is possibly because of the fact that your `enum`s are nested in your entity. You need to access it on entity name.

You can change your `setParameter` code to: -

```
query.setParameter("nationality", EmployeeType.NATIONALITY.LOCAL);
query.setParameter("type", EmployeeType.TYPE.HOURLY);
```